# how to customize nix package builder script

Tags: cmake, libxml2, nix

The root problem is that nix uses autoconf to build `libxml2-2.9.14` instead of cmake, and a consequence of this is that the cmake-configuration is missing (details like version number, platform specific dependencies like `ws2_32` etc which are needed by my project cmake scripts). `libxml2-2.9.14` already comes with cmake configuration and works nicely, except that nix does not use it (I guess they have their own reasons).

Therefore I would like to reuse the `libxml2-2.9.14` nix package and override the builder script with my own (which is a trivial cmake dance).

Here is my attempt:

```
 defaultPackage = forAllSystems (system:
        let
          pkgs = nixpkgsFor.${system};
          cmakeLibxml = pkgs.libxml2.overrideAttrs( o: rec {
            PROJECT_ROOT = builtins.getEnv "PWD";
            builder = "${PROJECT_ROOT}/nix-libxml2-builder.sh";
          });
        in
```

Where `nix-libxml2-builder.sh` is my script calling cmake with all the options I need. It fails like this:

```
       last 1 log lines:
       > bash: /nix-libxml2-builder.sh: No such file or directory
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/andvld0jy9zxrscxyk96psal631awp01-libxml2-2.9.14.drv'.
```

As you can see the issue is that PROJECT_ROOT does not get set (ignored) and I do not know how to feed my builder script.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `PROJECT_ROOT = builtins.getEnv "PWD";` that does not set a environment variable though to my understanding? Maybe `builder = "${PROJECT_ROOT}/nix-libxml2-builder.sh";` should reference `${PWD}` instead? Or some other mechanism to set the path.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Yeah, that was my first attempt, it did not work though, that's why I tried this `getEnv`. I think ${PWD} is also futile: nix changes the directory to a separate build directory, so PWD would not refer to my project directory anymore. I also tried setting PROJECT_DIR outside  `cmakeLibxml`, but that would no longer be functionally-pure, probably will break basic nix assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the use of `defaultPackage` in your snippet, you use flakes. [Flakes are evaluated in pure evaluation mode](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Flakes#Making_your_evaluations_pure), which means there is no way to influence the build from outside. Hence, `getEnv` always returns an empty string (unfortunately, this is not properly documented).

There is no need to refer to the builder script via `$PWD`. The whole flake is copied to the nix store so you can use your files directly. For example:

```hs
builder = ./nix-libxml2-builder.sh;
```

That said, the build will probably still fail, because `cmake` will not be available in the build environment. You would have to override `nativeBuildInputs` attribute to add cmake there.

Comment: *nativeBuildInputs